# Mocking JasonNode using Mockito

Tags: java, json, mockito, objectmapper

I am trying to write unit tests for the following snippet

```
>  private List<Car> getCar(SQSEvent.SQSMessage sqsMessage) throws
> JsonProcessingException {
>         final JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(sqsMessage.getBody());
>         final String items = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(node.get("Message").textValue());
>         return objectMapper.readValue(items, new TypeReference<List<Car>>() {
>         });
>     }
```

Here is the test code:

```
@Test
    public void dummyTest() {
        mockStatic(StringEscapeUtils.class);
        when(mockObjectMapper.readTree(sqsMessage.getBody())).thenReturn(node);
        when(node.get(any(String.class)).textValue()).thenReturn("node");
        when(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(anyString())).thenReturn("Mock");
 when(mockObjectMapper.readValue("Mock", new TypeReference<List<Car>>(){})).thenReturn(carList);
        // call to the method
    }
```

I am not able to mock List returned, it is returning null. Please help. Thanks